# Cross Domain REST Calls - Always 401 before 200 received

Tags: javascript, rest, authentication, cross-domain

I am attempting to create a REST call across domains (we have different farms with different domains in our organization.  I am not doing this through an app, but instead I am doing it via a CEWP loading my javascript files on a site page.  All I am attempting to do is get the data from a list item.  I am attempting this with an AJAX call that has the properties: `withCredentials= true` and `crossDomain: true`.  When I watch the flow in Fiddler, the call is returning a 200 that contains the data in JSON, but before each 200 I get a 401 and I believe this is what my function is getting back. Eventually getting the 200 doesn't do me any good because the 401 is going back to the function call (I think).

Here's my code:

```
function getListItemByIDAjax(siteURL, listName, itemID, complete, failure) {
$.ajax({
    url: siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + itemID + ")",
    method: 'GET',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain:true,
    beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest){
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
    },
    cache: true,
    success: function (data) {
            // Returning the results
            complete(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
            // Returning the results
            failure(data);
    }
});
}
```

I can't be the first person trying to accomplish this, but I sure am not finding any information out there that seems to work in this instance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to address this? I'm having an identical issue

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Authentication (NTLM), getting two 401 before one 200 is completely expected: this is the way challenge/response works. You usually don't notice it with same-domain calls since you're already authenticated with a session cookie.

Comment: Ok, so is my function call grabbing the response from the 401?  If so, is there a way to get the 200 data?

Comment: Are you unable to tell if your error or completion handlers are being triggered? Can you add simple logging to test? The fact that the data is coming back on the 200 should mean your call is working fine.

Answer (score -2):

In SharePoint to make cross domain calls, you need to create request using SP.RequestExceutor.JS

see the below MSDN links

[SP.RequestExecutor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn735924.aspx)

[Access Data from Cross Domain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927.aspx)

Comment: The RequestExecutor is specifically for Apps and calling from the appweb to the host web, or to other site collections from the app *within the same tenant* - the question is regarding code not called from an app, and to a totally separate SharePoint farm.

I think this is worth a try, but I do not believe it will work, nor is it the recommended approach for this scenario.

Comment: I agree, this is not meant to work in this case.  I also didn't expect it to work, but in order to be sure I did infact run it.  Failed as expected.